# PHP before action and after action

Tags: php, yii, action

I would like to know how can I do something similar with beforeAction() and afterAction() from Yii.

I need to have the same behavior in my PHP like those two functions from Yii and I don't know where to start from.

What I really need in my case is that every time a function executes, it has to reload some parameters and after the function executes it's code, it has to set them again.

The first action can be done in the constructor but the second one can only be done using a callback and this is not quite lovely.

I also need to implement this because the number of functions is about 30 and each one is doing something similar. Using this kind of behaviors I'll reduce the code size with about 70%.

```
function a1(){
  load();
  procA1();
  set();
}

function a2(){
  load();
  procA2();
  set();
}

function a3(){
  load();
  procA3();
  set();
}
and so on...
```

Comment: If first action can be done with constructor, how about destructor for second (afterAction)?

Comment: Please add some code of what you have.

Comment: @MrBr I cannot use a destructor because my class will be used again later.

Comment: @RonniSkansing I cannot post the code. I may try to show you the structure

Comment: If you need beforeAction each time you call function, you can't use object constructor for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**
Use `call_user_func($function_name, (optional) $parametrs)` + magic `__call` method. It is exactly the same as in Yii.

```
public function __call($name,$args) {
   if (method_exists($this,$name)) {
      $this->beforeAction();
      $ret =  call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $args);
      $this->afterAction();
      return $ret;
   }
}
```

Now you can simple call `$object->a3()`. You can have function named `a3` in the class, but add `private` modifier to it.

Comment: Yes, this is a very good and nice solution, but still, how those two methods from Yii are implemented?